# Google maps API, custom marker issue (Can't really explain in the title)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I have the following Javascript code for some custom markers:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initialise)

//Initialises the map view
function initialise() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4113594, -2.1571162),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    //Creates the actual Map object
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapArea"), mapOptions);


    setMarkers(map, myLocations);
}
var myLocations = [
    ['Stockport Town Hall', 'This is the town hall. Where things... happen.', 'townhall.jpg', 53.406, -2.158215, 'images/markers/townhall.png'],
    ['Stockport Town Centre', 'This is the centre of town. Where there are shops. And food. and... stuff', 'stockportcentre.jpg', 53.4175146, -2.1490619,
        'images/markers/shopping.png'
    ],
    ['Stockport College', 'This is Stockport college. Where learning happens.', 'stockportcollege.jpg', 53.4040427, -2.1587963, 'images/markers/Learning.png'],
    ['Stockport Train station', 'This is the train station. Where you catch trains.', 'stockporttrainstation.jpg', 53.4056234, -2.1637525, 'images/markers/train.png']

];



function setMarkers(map, myLocations) {
    for (var i in myLocations) {
        var name = myLocations[i][0];
        var info = myLocations[i][1];
        var image = myLocations[i][2];
        var lat = myLocations[i][3];
        var lng = myLocations[i][4];
        var indivIcon = myLocations[i][5];
        var latlngset;
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: name,
            position: latlngset,
            icon: indivIcon
        });


        //content here!

        var infoContent = '<h3>' + name + '</h3>' + info +
            '<br /><img width = "128" height = "128" src = "images/' + image + ' " ' + '</div>';



        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(
            marker, 'click',
            function() {
                infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

    }
}
```

Now, the markers work just fine. I can open them up, they auto-close and go to other markers, but the weird issue is: The infoWindows all show the "Stockport Train Station" information and I have no idea why. What is it I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's happening is this.  You're looping over all your locations, creating a marker for each one, and that's fine.  And for each marker, you're creating an event listener, which only gets called when a marker is clicked on.

Within that loop, you're basically doing this for every marker, updating the value of the `infoContent` variable each time:

```
var infoContent = "...";
```

So at the end of the loop, infoContent will be equal to whatever you set it to for the last marker, something like

```
'<h3>Stockport Train station</h3> etc...'
```

So then whenever you click on any of the markers, it executes this function:

```
infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
infowindow.open(map, this);
```

So it correctly opens the current marker.  And it sets the content of the infowindow to whatever `infoContent` is... i.e. always the value given to it at the end of that loop.

Instead try this,  set the content into a property on the marker, then use that:

```
    var infoContent = '<h3>' + name + '</h3>' + info +
        '<br /><img width = "128" height = "128" src = "images/' + image + ' " ' + '</div>';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: name,
        position: latlngset,
        icon: indivIcon,
        content: infoContent 
    });
```

And then in your event listener you can refer to that directly:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(
        marker, 'click',
        function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.content);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
```